# How to adjust css grid images horizontal gap

Tags: css

Here is the HTML

```
<section className="section">
  <div className="image-grid">
      <img src="../imagegrid/img1.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img2.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img3.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img4.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img5.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img6.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img7.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img8.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img9.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img10.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img11.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img12.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img13.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img14.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img15.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
      <img src="../imagegrid/img16.jpg" alt="grid" ></img>
  </div>

</section>
```

Here is the CSS, I have used a grid to display images like this, and I want to keep the images looking like the attached picture below, but don't want to change the image size

```
.image-grid{
    padding: 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8,1fr);
    grid-auto-columns: 100px;
    grid-auto-rows: 200px;
    gap: 15px;
    
   
}

.image-grid img{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    /* border: solid red; */
    border-radius:20px ;
    
}

.image-grid img:nth-child(odd){
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.image-grid img:nth-child(9){
    opacity: 0;
}
```

This is what it looks like now

[image: Here space between column is too much I want make image more closer]

Here is an example of what I want this to look like

[image: example]

Comment: Just a note, an image is a self closing tag: `<img />`, no need for the `<img></img>`

Comment: @xmr6204 actually, i have not find the difference betwen first and second pciture. what you want ?

Comment: the horizontal gap is different, first image horizontal gap  is too much

Comment: width of your image should be 100%, because it is 70%, you are creating an extra blank space on the right of each image

Answer (score 1):

In your grid container, you should replace `grid-template-columns: repeat(8,1fr);` by `grid-template-columns: repeat(8,100px);`.
You can remove this: `grid-auto-columns: 100px;`

And by your image set them to `width: 100%;`.
The gap in your code comes from this `width: 70%;` what is the point of this ?

### Demo:

```css
.image-grid{
    padding: 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    /*grid-template-columns: repeat(8,1fr);*/
    /* Replaced by: */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8,100px);
    /*grid-auto-columns: 100px;*/ /* This is useless */
    grid-auto-rows: 200px;
    grid-gap: 15px;
    
   
}

.image-grid img{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Shoud be 100% not 70%, width of the column should be manage in the grid container setting */
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    /* border: solid red; */
    border-radius:20px ;
    
    margin-right:-30%;
}

.image-grid img:nth-child(odd){
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.image-grid img:nth-child(9){
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="image-grid">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/357f94/00ff04" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ff04/357f94" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/357f94/00ff04" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ff04/357f94" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/357f94/00ff04" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ff04/357f94" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/357f94/00ff04" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ff04/357f94" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/357f94/00ff04" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/357f94/00ff04" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ff04/357f94" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/357f94/00ff04" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ff04/357f94" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/357f94/00ff04" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ff04/357f94" alt="grid" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/357f94/00ff04" alt="grid" />
      
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `grid-gap`

```css
.image-grid{
    padding: 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8,1fr);
    grid-auto-columns: 100px;
    grid-auto-rows: 200px;
    grid-gap: 15px; /* here instead of gap */
}
```

Comment: I did not work. I only want to make images close horizontally

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I change the code like this:

```css
.image-grid{
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8,150px);
    grid-auto-columns: 10px;
    grid-auto-rows: 200px;
    grid-gap: 15px;
    
   
}

.image-grid img{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius:20px ;
    
}
```